# Reading a large text file using python is way slower than the same code for reading the same text using Matlab, Any idea why?

Tags: python, xml, matlab, text

I have the following code in Matlab for reading a text file  Text file is having XML format but I read it as a text file:

```
    function [jointAngleData,PositionData, AccelerationData,OrientationData, 
    AngularVelocityData,AngularAccelerationData,TimeStamps] = getDatafromMVNX 
    (file,eliminate_samples)
    fid=fopen (file);
    currentline=fgetl(fid);
    jointAngleData =[];
    PositionData = [];
    AccelerationData = [];
    OrientationData = [];
    AngularVelocityData = [];
    AngularAccelerationData = [];
    while ischar(currentline)

if (contains(currentline,'<jointAngle>'))  
     [data,~]=strsplit(currentline,'<\D*>','DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
     currentlinedata = str2num(data{2}); %#ok<*ST2NM>
     jointAngleData = [jointAngleData ; currentlinedata];  %#ok<*AGROW>
 end
 if (contains(currentline,'<position>'))
     [data,~]=strsplit(currentline,'<\D*>','DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
     currentlinedata = str2num(data{2});
     PositionData = [PositionData ; currentlinedata]; 
 end

 if (contains(currentline,'<acceleration>'))
     [data,~]=strsplit(currentline,'<\D*>','DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
     currentlinedata = str2num(data{2});
     AccelerationData = [AccelerationData ; currentlinedata]; 
 end

 if (contains(currentline,'<orientation>'))
     [data,~]=strsplit(currentline,'<\D*>','DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
     currentlinedata = str2num(data{2});
     OrientationData = [OrientationData ; currentlinedata]; 
 end
 if (contains(currentline,'<angularVelocity>'))
     [data,~]=strsplit(currentline,'<\D*>','DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
     currentlinedata = str2num(data{2});
     AngularVelocityData = [AngularVelocityData ; currentlinedata]; 
 end

 if (contains(currentline,'<angularAcceleration>'))
     [data,~]=strsplit(currentline,'<\D*>','DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
     currentlinedata = str2num(data{2});
     AngularAccelerationData = [AngularAccelerationData ; currentlinedata]; 
 end
 currentline=fgetl(fid);

 end
Data_ends = size(jointAngleData,1)-eliminate_samples;
jointAngleData = jointAngleData(1:Data_ends,:);
AccelerationData = AccelerationData(1:Data_ends,:);
OrientationData = OrientationData(4:Data_ends+3,:);
PositionData = PositionData(4:Data_ends+3,:);
AngularVelocityData = AngularVelocityData(1:Data_ends,:);
AngularAccelerationData = AngularAccelerationData(1:Data_ends,:);
TimeStamps = size(OrientationData,1);
end
```

for the same task I wrote a code in python :

```
def _read_feature_text(line):


   start = line.find('>')+1
   lend = line.find('</') 
   workingportion = line[start:lend]
   return pd.DataFrame([np.fromstring(workingportion,sep= ' ')])


def read_mvnx(mvnxfile):

 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 myfile  = open (mvnxfile,"r")
 contents = myfile.read()
 orientation = pd.DataFrame()
 positions = pd.DataFrame()
 velocities = pd.DataFrame()
 accelerations = pd.DataFrame()
 angularVelocities = pd.DataFrame()
 angularAccelerations = pd.DataFrame()
 jointAngles = pd.DataFrame()
 with myfile:

    wholefilecontent = myfile.readlines()
    #line = myfile.readline()
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    for line in wholefilecontent:

        if ('orientation' in line):
            orientation = orientation.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)
        elif ('position' in line):
            positions = positions.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)
        elif ('velocity' in line):
            velocities = velocities.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)
        elif ('acceleration' in line):
            accelerations = accelerations.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)
        elif ('angularVelocity' in line):
            angularVelocities = angularVelocities.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)
        elif ('angularAcceleration' in line):
            angularAccelerations = angularAccelerations.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)
        elif ('joinAngle' in line):
            jointAngles = jointAngles.append(_read_feature_text(line),ignore_index = True)

    elapsed = timeit.default_timer() -start_time
    print(elapsed)
```

I even tried to use regular expression and BeautifulSoup package. Neither gave me better timing. Any suggestion why?
Is there any other way to make it faster. By faster I mean way faster that this one is.

Comment: Yes, MATLAB is faster than Python. There are many, many questions here asking the same thing. Python is not made for speed.

Comment: Python is slower because it’s developers don’t care as much for speed as the developers of MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks Cris Luengo, for the comment. I haven't find any thing useful in terms of why it is this much slower or why it is slower in first place.But referring to my code, I figured out that what made it too much slow was the fact that after finding the data in each of the lines I converted it to a dataframe and append it to the end of the global dataframe. This conversion made it super slow. I fixed it by just having the data in a numpy array and then convert the whole numpy array into a dataframe at the end.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For my code, I figured out that what made it too much slow was the fact that after finding the data in each of the lines I converted it to a dataframe and append it to the end of the global dataframe. This conversion made it super slow. I fixed it by just having the data in a numpy array and then convert the whole numpy array into a dataframe at the end.

I also used xmltodic package to parse through the file rather than line by line parsing.